# Deserialize Json не получается

Tags: c#, json

Создал тип для десерилизации json:

```cs
public class AV_GQ_data
{
    public string datatype { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}

public class AV_Global_Quote
{
    public string name_answer { get; set; }
    public AV_GQ_data[] datas { get; set; }
}
```

Пытаюсь десериазовать следующий JSON-объект:

```json
{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "IBM",
        "02. open": "145.9500",
        "03. high": "146.9800",
        "04. low": "145.9200",
        "05. price": "146.5500",
        "06. volume": "2627999",
        "07. latest trading day": "2023-09-13",
        "08. previous close": "146.3000",
        "09. change": "0.2500",
        "10. change percent": "0.1709%"
    }
}
```

Следующим образом:

```cs
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
var aaa= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AV_Global_Quote>(client.DownloadString(queryUri), options);
```

В результате в `aaa` `null , null`. Подскажите что не так может быть.

Comment: https://json2csharp.com/, а тому, кто так отдает json, надо руки оторвать, имхо

Comment: а если записей придет 10000 создавать и описывать класс на 10000?  можно же как то сделать для ответа любой размерности .

Comment: {
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Monthly Adjusted Prices and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2023-09-13",
        "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Monthly Adjusted Time Series": {
        "2023-09-13": {
            "1. open": "147.2600",
            "2. high": "149.0000",
            "3. low": "145.8000",
            "4. close": "146.5500",
            "5. adjusted close": "146.5500",
            "6. volume": "26806661",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"

Comment: при такой структуре ваш конвертер предлагает создавать класс на каждую дату что неправильно  , и должно быть решение другое , за конвертер спасибо

Comment: Парсить руками, API отдает не в человеческом виде данные

Comment: Либо десериализируйте в `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` или Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>. Но таким вы мало чего добьетесь, второй пример таким образом не десериализуется. API сторонний или ваш?

Comment: api сторонний  https://www.alphavantage.co/

Comment: а что подробнее вам рассказать? В гугле миллон информации. Я сразу говорю, что с таким форматом ответов от API вам будет больно с ними работать

Comment: спасибо за ответы

Comment: Не вижу тут каких либо проблем с JSON. `Global Quote` - это список ключей и значений, вот в это и десериализуйте. В классе `AV_Global_Quote` (лучше переименуйте), создайте простой словарь `public Dictionary<string, string> GlobalQuote { get; set; }`, но так, как имя с пробелом, а в C# вы такое указать не можете, нужно повесить на это свойство еще атрибут `[JsonPropertyName("Global Quote")]`, в итоге получаете что-то [такое](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MVRoaK). Ну и где тут "больно с ним работать" ? Я не знаю... Единственное, конвертация в нужные типы, но это тоже решается.

Comment: Имхо, проще всего использовать [JsonObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonobject?view=net-7.0). Пример: [How to use a JSON document object model in System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ больно в том месте, где значение ключа становится тоже ключом, что человек показал выше, как вы это распарсите в Dictionary<string, string> мне интересно :)

Comment: @OwDafuq Вложенность ведь не отменяли, спокойно [словарями](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dFCYjE) десериализуется. В чем трудности-то? Любой динамичный ключ == +1 словарь. А если это статичный набор переменных, то можно написать конвертор, который преобразует это в простые переменные, избавив код от словаря.

Comment: Словарь в словаре... Думаю не надо объяснять, что такой подход успехом не веет, напишите минимальный пример конвертера для этой задачи и дайте ответ, даже интересно что выйдет

Comment: @OwDafuq Пинговать не забывайте. Словарь в словаре - почему успехом не веет? Если все данные динамичны, то так динамичные данные и получаются. Скажу даже больше, внутри десериализатора используются как ни странно словари, к которым также можно получить доступ (как сказали вон выше, используя `JsonObject`), только там совсем структуры не будет, будет что-то, как в ответе ниже. Что касается конвертора - честно, мне лень, если интересно из чего состоять будет, то получение `JsonObject`, а затем `result.Key = obj["..."]["..."]; ... return result;`, простое заполнение класса.

Answer (score 0):

Можно десериализовать любой json в JObject:

JObject jo  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData??"{}");

после чего обращаться к полям объектов следующим образом:

if (jo.ContainsKey("header")) myheader = jo.Value("header");

либо:
jo.TryGetValue("header", out myHeader);

Comment: 1. Речь про `System.Text.Json`, стандартный парсер JSON, а у вас речь про `Json.NET`, что не соответствует поставленной задаче. 2. Это плохой совет, особенно когда есть готовые решения без перебора вот так дерева объектов.